# Layout not appearing - rather a blank screen

Tags: c#, xaml, mono

I am new to Android development and have encountered a problem with displaying a Layout I have created - I have a main activity and a layout that loads at startup - and I would like a another Layout to be shown when a button is pressed - but instead of showing the other layout a blank screen is shown (there is a textfield on the other layout so it should not be blank) - have I missed something here?

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)

    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button num1 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.num1Button);

        num1.Click += delegate {

            //button.Text = string.Format ("This is runtime text");
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Num1Layout);
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello%2C_multi-screen_applications . I think it may help you.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, actually what I was doing should be valid - I actually found that Xamarin studio had corrupted the layout somehow.. (I simply recreated the layout and it worked fine) It doesn't fill me with much confidence about the product - especially not to people new to it :/